# How to find records in a bson object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
var otherLanguages=[ "English","Arabic","French"];

var first, second;
db.collection.find({ $and: [ { "Language" : { $nin : otherLanguages} },{"Language":{ $ne:null}} ]}).forEach(function(obj){
```

shell out 341 docs one by one. In these docs,I want to find out documents that satisfy two if statements. Later, I want to collect the count it.

```
if (obj.find({ $and: [{'POS': { $eq: "Past" } },{'Desp': { $ne: null } }] })) { first= first+1;}
if (obj.find({ $and: [{'POS': { $eq: "Past" } },{'Desp': { $eq: null } }] })) {second= second+1;}
    }); 
    print (first,second)
```

I know that I cannot use find() function on the obj, but Is there a way to search on this "bson obj" to find the count.
If this is not feasible, then please suggest a way to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you can achieve that by using the aggregation framework like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    // filter out all documents that you don't care about
    $match: {
        "Language": { $nin: otherLanguages, $ne: null },
        "POS": "Past"
    },
}, {
    // then split into groups...
    $group: {
        _id: { $eq: [ "$Desp", null ] }, // ...one for the "eq: null" and one for the "ne: null"
        "count": { $sum: 1 } // ...and count the number of documents in each group
    }
})
```